# Does a higher body temperature slow the corona virus down?

Tags: virology, coronavirus

The corona virus appearantly does not like high temperature:
[High Temperature and High Humidity Reduce the Transmission of COVID-19](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/Papers.cfm?abstract_id=3551767)
Also it seems that higher body temperatures helps the immune system to work better: [Elevated body temperature helps certain types of immune cells to work better, evidence suggests](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/11/111101130200.htm)

Should therefore someone who suspect they may have the corona virus or possibly another cold virus and do not experience fever try to elevate their body temperature slightly (say 0.5-1 degrees celsius) by dressing extra warm?

This is postulated [here](https://www.bmj.com/rapid-response/2011/10/29/coronavirus-may-be-killed-higher-body-temperature).

Does this sound plausible to you?

Comment: SE Biology is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, and questions are generally answered by people with biological rather than medical or epidemiological expertise. Although I understand your concern about the coronavirus outbreak, your question asks for subjective view on measures to avoid the disease. Such questions are doubly off-topic here. I advise you to consult more appropriate reputable sources for such information, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SARS-CoV-2 is believed to have spilled over into humans [from a Rhinopholus (horseshoe bat) reservoir](https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200211-sitrep-22-ncov.pdf). During flight, bats' body temperature is maintained at levels associated with fever in other mammals. Rhinolophus bats are reported to reach skin temperatures of 41 C during flight. (From [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4012789/) which describes why bats might be special sources for zoonotic viruses)
So, this virus is likely adapted to survive higher temperatures than a human host.